# Focus disappearing when opening a UIAlertController on tvOS 10 GM

Tags: swift, tvos, uialertcontroller, uialertaction, tvos10

I want to display a `UIAlertController` on top of a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView` inside. The collection view needs to focus on startup, so I overrode the `preferredFocusableView` variable as follows:

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    return self.collectionView
}
```

With tvOS 9 all worked fine: the alert controller opened properly and I was able to choose one of the `UIAlertAction`s displayed.

On tvOS 10 Golden Master, after opening the alert controller and scrolling to another action, the focus disappears from the screen and I'm unable to scroll to other actions or tapping on the Menu button of the Siri Remote. The app remains stuck in the alert controller and I can hear the scrolling sound when I try to scroll to other actions but nothing happens on screen. I have to force quit the app and reopen it.

[image]
[image]

This is the code of the app. I tried to set the `preferredFocusableView` to `alertController.preferredFocusedView` or by removing the focus methods of the collection view but with no results.

```
var alertController : UIAlertController?

func showAlert() {

    alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Example title", message: "Example description", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: .Default) { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        //call to another method
    }

    // action2, action3, action4...

    let action5 = UIAlertAction(title: "Option 5", style: .Default) { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        //call to another method
    }

    let actionDismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Destructive) { (action : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.alertController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    alertController!.addAction(action1)
    alertController!.addAction(action2)
    alertController!.addAction(action3)
    alertController!.addAction(action4)
    alertController!.addAction(action5)
    alertController!.addAction(actionDismiss)

    alertController!.preferredAction = action1

    self.presentViewController(alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    if self.alertController != nil {
        return self.alertController!.preferredFocusedView
    } else {
        return self.collectionView
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `showAlert`?

Comment: @DanielStorm when the user taps with the remote on a button inside the view controller

Comment: preferredFocusedView was deprecated in tvOS10 https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifocusenvironment/1616830-preferredfocusedview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple just replied to my radar:

> Inside the attached application, you’re overwriting the functionality
>   of `UIScrollView` in an extension to return `true` for
>   `canBecomeFocused()`, which is the cause of these unexpected side
>   effects.  The focus seems to be disappearing when moving to a second
>   `UIAlertController` option; however, it is actually transferring focus
>   to the scroll view wrapped around the various components of the
>   `UIAlertController`, since this is now allowed due to the extension
>   mentioned above.
>
> **To solve this, create a custom subclass of `UIScrollView` to be used
>   only in the instances where `canBecomeFocused()` must return `true`.**

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the entire systems focus engine. Try this:

```
// MARK: - Update Focus Helper
var viewToFocus: UIView? = nil {
    didSet {
        if viewToFocus != nil {
            self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
            self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    if viewToFocus != nil {
        return viewToFocus
    } else {
        return super.preferredFocusedView
    }
}
```

Then set your alert as the view when you want the focus to change to it:

```
viewToFocus = someView
```

Comment: Still not working :( I'm setting the focus after the presentation of the UIAlertController. The two methods work correctly but the focus still disappear.